# Any new axioms for the natural numbers since Peano?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, peano-axioms

Have any axioms in addition to usual 2nd-order Peano axioms been found to significantly extend the class of derivable propositions about natural numbers?

Comment: Yes. I believe they are mostly axioms on the existence of large cardinals: measurable, compact, etc.

Comment: Those are axioms of set theory, though. There are such axioms that greatly affect the theory of the reals, eg the axiom of determinacy, but I don't know that they make a notable difference to the theory of the natural numbers.

Comment: @bof You say "mostly." Are there other new axioms for the natural numbers not dealing with large cardinals?

Comment: Lawvere in the 60s developed a [description of natural numbers](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number_object) equivalent to Peano's when in **Set**, which I suppose is relevant here (perhaps with a judicious substitution for **Set**); I could be wrong.

Comment: Not that I know of. I said "mostly" just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @KevinCarlson AD implies Con(ZFC + measurable cardinals) which is a statement about natural numbers.

Comment: @KevinCarlson From Wiki: "The axiom of determinacy is inconsistent with the axiom of choice." That doesn't sound very promising. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy

Comment: How far will the usual 2nd order Peano axioms get you in number theory? Might they handle all theorems and proofs involving sets no larger than countably infinite? Wouldn't that cover just about all of number theory?

Comment: The Axiom of Choice is irrelevant, because any arithmetical statement that is provable in ZF+AC is provable in ZF. Not so for the Axiom of Determinacy.

Comment: But isn't AC necessary for the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, etc.?